# Heap Area - PS Old Gen

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

As I know, we have three areas in heap:

- PS Eden Space
- PS Survivor Space
- PS Old Gen

I want to know  when Old Gen will be garbage collected, because when I am using jconsole to monitor these spaces:

PS Eden Space is garbage collected properly
PS Survivor Space also garbage collected properly.
But PS Old Gen is increasing and I have not noticed any decrease in that.

Why is this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the java8 GC not collect for over 11 hours?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613251/why-does-the-java8-gc-not-collect-for-over-11-hours)

Comment: Resolved the issue? I have the same problem: PS Old Gen increases over the time; it does not decrease also forcing the GC from jConsole (my running application is WSO2 EI 6.1.0). @the8472 It seems like a different problem.