# JVM memory management

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, jvm

I was trying to get to know how memory-management work after I got a JVM-memory-allocation-crash in a MPI program of mine. In order to do this, I added the lines as can be seen underneath.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MPIException {
    System.out.println("memory upon initialisation: " + (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() >> 20) + "MB");
    //run some with some loops and a lot of variables...
    System.out.println("memory when finished: " + (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() >> 20) + "MB");
}
```

I ran this code and could see how the heap size had increased, but when I added the line `System.gc();` to my code, the heap size didn't expand anymore.

My question thus is: why does JVM seem to prefer expanding the heap over doing some garbage collection? I would expect the JVM to rather first try garbage collection before further memory allocation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: the GCs have to balance various goals, see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/28614001/1362755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JVM assumes that you are OK with it allocating as much heap as you have allowed with `-Xmx`. More heap headroom means greater GC throughput and less frequent GC pauses. It is up to you to decide how much RAM you are willing to invest in helping your JVM perform well. At least that's the default reasoning; you may influence JVM's choice with a large arsenal of configurable options.

Comment: Why did they decide that throughput should be more important than memory footprint? Isn't garbage collection 'cheaper' than memory allocation?

Comment: Memory allocation is dirt-cheap and most of the time consists of just incrementing a thread-local pointer indicating the next free location. GC is far more elaborate and less cache-friendly. Doing more GCing in one go provides better throughput than smaller, more frequent GCs.