# Java heap size growing too big with Infinispan cache

Tags: java, caching, garbage-collection, jboss6.x, infinispan

I am using an Infinispan cache to store values. The code writes to the cache every 10 minutes and the cache reaches a size of about 400mb. 
It has a time to live of about 2 hours, and the maximum entries is 16 million although currently in my tests the number of entries doesn't go above 2 million or so (I can see this by checking the mbeans/metrics in jconsole).

When I start jboss the java heap size is 1.5Gb to 2Gb. The -Xmx setting for the maximum allocated memory to jboss is 4Gb.

When I disable the Infinispan cache the heap memory usage stays flat at around 1.5Gb to 2Gb. It is very constant and stays at that level.

=> The problem is: when I have the Infinispan cache *enabled* the java heap size grows to about 3.5Gb/4Gb which is way more than expected.
I have done a heap dump to check the size of the cache in Eclipse MAT and it is only 300 or 400mb (which is ok).
So I would expect the memory usage to go to 2.5Gb and stay steady at that level, since the initial heap size is 2Gb and the maximum cache size should only be around 500mb.

However it continues to grow and grow over time. Every 2 or 3 hours a garbage collection is done and that brings the usage down to about 1 or 1.5Gb but it then increases again within 30 minutes up to 3.5Gb.
The number of entries stays steady at about 2 million so it is not due to just more entries going in to the cache. (Also the number of evictions stays at 0).

What could be holding on to this amount of memory if the cache is only 400-500mb? 
Is it a problem with my garbage collection settings? Or should I look at Infinispan settings?

Thanks!

Edit: you can see the heap size over time here.
What is strange is that even after what looks like a full GC, the memory shoots back up again to 3Gb. This corresponds to more entries going into the cache.
[image: Java heap over time]

Edit: It turns out this has nothing to do with Infinispan. I narrowed down the problem to a single line of code that is using a lot of memory (about 1Gb more than without the call).
But I do think more and more memory is being taken by the Infinispan cache, naturally because more entries are being added over the 2 hour time to live.

**I also need to have upwards of 50 users query on Infinispan. When the heap reaches a high value like this (even without the memory leak mentioned above), I know it's not an error scenario in java however I need as much memory available as possible.
Is there any way to "encourage" a heap dump past a certain point? I have tried using GC options to collect at a given proportion of heap for the old gen but in general the heap usage tends to creep up.**

Comment: it's allowing as much as it's allowed to, there is really no technical problem here, just your expectations not aligning with the JVM's decision-making. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28614001/1362755

Comment: What's the cache configuration you are using?

Comment: timeToLive is 2 hours, max entries is 16 million (in the run in the screenshot, it loaded about 2 million entries), eviction strategy is LRU, transactional is false, cache mode is replicated async, cache visibility type is cluster. Number of distributed owners is 10.

Comment: @user2533268 What version of Infinispan? What cache mode? How big are your values? 300mb sounds suspiciously low for 2 million entries, since Infinispan adds ~ 100 bytes of overhead for each entry. Perhaps you're looking at the shallow size instead of the retained size in MAT? Note that Infinispan also had/has a fixed overhead of (pointer size) * maxEntries, which would be 128mb if you're not using CompressedOops (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-4126).

Comment: @DanBerindei Thanks, looking at a heap dump the key object is 32 bytes and the value (java.lang.Double) is 24 bytes, so 56 bytes in total.

Comment: @DanBerindei Thanks, The version is 'Hoptimus Prime' 7.1.1.Final, and the cache mode is replicated async. So that would be 156 for each entry including overhead. Each loading session loads 225,000 entries so I would expect about 35 megabytes to be added to the heap each time. But it's actually more like 125 megabytes for some reason, even trying several different garbage collector algorithms.

Comment: @user2533268 Could you get a heap dump before you insert any entries? ISPN-4126 was only fixed in version 7.2, so I'd expect an empty cache to use 125mb, and the entries to occupy another 35mb on top of that. Unless you actually expect to have 16 million entries in the cache, I suggest either lowering maxEntries or removing it altogether.

Comment: @DanBerindei Thanks I can get a heap dump when I start jboss, is there anything I should be looking for? I will look at leaving the time to live set only, and removing the maxEntries.

Comment: @user2533268 If you keep `maxEntries`, you can compare the startup heap dump with your existing heap dump to see how big your entries really are. Like I said, I expect the 125mb to be just the Infinispan overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably what you're seeing is the JVM not collecting objects which have been evicted from the cache. Cache's in general have a curious relationship with the prevailing idea of generational GC.

The generational GC idea is that, broadly speaking, there are two types of objects in the JVM - short lived ones, which are used and thrown away quickly, and longer lived ones, which are usually used throughout the lifetime of the application. In this model you want to tune your GC so that you put most of your effort attempting to identify the short lived objects. This means that you avoid looking at the long-lived objects as much as possible.

Cache's disrupt this pattern by having some intermediate-length object lifespans (i.e. a few seconds / minutes / hours, depending on your cache). These objects often get promoted to the tenured generation, where they're not usually looked at until a full GC becomes necessary, even after they've been evicted from the cache.

If this is what's happening then you've a couple of choices:

- ignore it, let the full GC semantics do its thing and just be aware that this is what's happening.
- try to tune the GC so that it takes longer for objects to get promoted to the tenured generation. There are some [GC flags](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) which can help with that.

Comment: Thanks, I put up an image with the amount of heap memory used over time. What is interesting is that even after a full GC the memory goes back again over 3Gb very quickly.

Comment: You can see the program phases in the GC diagram: 7 minutes of heavy processing with lot's of garbage produced, maybe that is when you update the cache? Then it is 8 minutes steady&calm flow, maybe you are just accessing the cache? The full GC happens in the phase of the heavy processing, because you have a high allocation rate. Of course, it will go back to 3GB very quickly.

Comment: Since the full GC happens at a third of you update phase two thirds of the data you replace next, will be stuck until the next full GC. For experimentation you could add a System.gc() just after the update phase and see what over all difference it makes.

Comment: @cruftex Hi from within JVisualVM I can trigger a garbage collection. This does a collection similar to the one in the screenshot and it is cleared out down to about 1Gb, but it increases again when entries are being put into the cache.

Comment: After experimenting with several different garbage collectors, I found exactly what people have said here. In the end the fix for this problem was not to "fix" the garbage collector, instead I found a very costly call (in terms of memory) that I was repeating thousands of times.
JVisualVM was very handy to see the amount of memory used by each method. Had I looked at that first it would have avoided a lot of debugging.